# how to disable query string from appearing on url on submitting modal form?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I created a modal form for submitting single text input. I want to submit through ajax without reloading the browser but whenever i submit the form get close automatically, the page refreshed and the input data get display on url as if it was submitted with GET method even though i have declared type: "POST", on ajax. Please help me get though this.

I am using codeigniter 3.9

html form:

```
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Update Product Location</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 form-group"><input class="form-control" name="pincodeloc" id="pincodeloc" placeholder="Enter pincode"/></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" id="prod_id" value="" readonly/>
    <div class="col-md-4"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addproductlocbtn">Save</button></div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div> 

ajax code:
$("#addproductlocbtn").click(function() {
        addproductlocation();
    }); 

function addproductlocation() {
        var returnval = true;
        if (returnval==true) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl + "admin/product/productlocation",
                    data: {
                        pincode: $("#pincodeloc").val(),
                        prodid: $("#prod_id").val()
                    }
                })
                .done(function(msg) {
                    if (msg) {
                        $('#emsg').html('');
                        $("#pincodeloc").val('');
                        $("#prod_id").val('');
                    } else {
                        $('#success_msg').html('');
                        $('#emsg').html('<p>' + msg + '</p>');
                    }
                });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

query string on url appear as:
www.xyz.com/dashboard/product?pincodeloc=&prod_id=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the page then use the `<button type="button">` not `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: Also, I think 3.1.11 is the latest version of Codeigniter. How can you use version 3.9?

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery form: https://github.com/jquery-form/form

Or use Event.preventDefault():

```
$("#addproductlocbtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addproductlocation();
});
```

Comment: Also, you can use **return false;** after calling the addproductlocation()